# Failed to resolve Bintray dependency

Tags: android, sdk, bintray

I've created a maven repository on https://bintray.com named it "maven", and I've added an aar library to it. But Android Studio can't build the project because:

```
Failed to resolve: com.danileron
```

The most confusing thing about it, is that if I reduce library version from:

```
implementation 'com.danileron.sdk:test_sdk:1.0.1'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.danileron.sdk:test_sdk:1.0.0'
```

Android Studio will warn me that :

```
A newer version of com.danileron.sdk:test_sdk than 1.0.0 is available: 1.0.1
```

So, it knows about the library but when I build project it can't resolve it?

Project's build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://webbey.bintray.com/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://webbey.bintray.com/maven"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

webbey is organisation in this case

Comment: Did you configure your repository? If not the default in `jcenter` or `maven-central`. Both don't hold `com.danileron`

Comment: Looking from your Bintray repository, looks like the `.arr` file isn't under the pom. so metadata is for pom only.

Comment: @Royg I'm not sure, do you mean: have I added repository to project's gradle file? I have edited question and added the project's configuration file

Comment: your `pom` file version says `<version>1.0.0</version>` and not `<version>1.0.1</version>`, see here: https://webbey.bintray.com/maven/com/danileron/sdk/test_sdk/1.0.1/

Comment: Your `arr` file isn't under the `.pom` file, see here: https://webbey.bintray.com/maven/com/danileron/sdk/test_sdk_module/1.0.1/

Comment: Update the `.pom` version to 1.0.1 and move the `arr` file to the `.pom` directory.

Comment: @Royg Thanks man. Saved my day. Maybe you should add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in this question.

1. The `.pom` file version was 1.0.0 and not 1.0.1, this gave the warning.
2. The `.arr` file wasn't located with the `.pom` file. The `maven-metadata.xml` held only the `.pom` and not the actual artifact, so the dependency couldn't be resolved.